# Overloading arithmetic operations for C++11 Python wrapper

Tags: python, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm working on a Python wrapper.

```
// wraps Python's Object primitive
class Object 
{...}

// wraps Python's Float primitive
class Float : Object 
{...}

// wraps Python's Float primitive
class Long : Object 
{...}
```

(Note Python has one primitive for integer types and another for floating-point types).

All primitives inherit from Object in the wrapper (Object contains the pointer to the underlying Python object)

For `Prim1 : Object` and `Prim2 : Object`,

```
Prim1 + Prim2
```

...can be handled through Python's C-API function `PyNumber_Add`

This will handle:

```
Float + Long
String + Float
Dict + Dict
etc., all kinds of stuff...
```

However, I need to implement things like:

```
Float + double
Float + int
Long + double
```

i.e. Mixing a C++ type with a Python type.

And I'm not sure how to implement this.

I've currently got a set of macros:

```
#define OP( op, func, param_a, param_b, expr_A, expr_B ) \
    inline Object operator op( param_a, param_b ) \
    { \
        return Object{ func(expr_A,expr_B), borrow_ref }; \
    }

#define OPS( ... ) \
    OP( +, PyNumber_Add         , __VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( -, PyNumber_Subtract    , __VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( *, PyNumber_Multiply    , __VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( /, PyNumber_TrueDivide  , __VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( %, PyNumber_Remainder   , __VA_ARGS__ )

#define BI_( param_a, param_b, expr_A, expr_B ) \
    OPS( param_a, param_b, expr_A, expr_B ) \
    OPS( param_b, param_a, expr_B, expr_A )

//------------------------------------------------------------

OPS( const Object& a, const Object& b   , a.ptr(),        b.ptr() )
BI_( const Object& a, int b             , a.ptr(),  Long{b}.ptr() )
BI_( const Object& a, long b            , a.ptr(),  Long{b}.ptr() )
BI_( const Object& a, double b          , a.ptr(), Float{b}.ptr() )

#undef BI_
#undef UNI
#undef OPS
#undef OP
```

It works, but I'm not sure if this is going to handle all situations.  I'm also guessing it isn't the best way to do the job.

I am considering:

- handling `Object op Object` within the Object class:

  ```
  Object operator+( const Object& rhs ) const { return Object{ PyNumber_Add       ( ptr(), rhs.ptr() ) }; }
  Object operator-( const Object& rhs ) const { return Object{ PyNumber_Subtract  ( ptr(), rhs.ptr() ) }; }
  Object operator*( const Object& rhs ) const { return Object{ PyNumber_Multiply  ( ptr(), rhs.ptr() ) }; }
  Object operator/( const Object& rhs ) const { return Object{ PyNumber_TrueDivide( ptr(), rhs.ptr() ) }; }
  Object operator%( const Object& rhs ) const { return Object{ PyNumber_Remainder ( ptr(), rhs.ptr() ) }; }
  ```
- maybe I can use templates to handle the other situations

  Something like this?:

  ```
  template< Foo /*derives from Object*/, Bar /*doesn't*/ >
  Object operator+(Foo foo, Bar bar) 
  { 
      return foo + Object{bar}; 
  }
  ```

  i.e. somehow force promoting Bar to an Object (Object can contain constructors for promoting from native C++ types), then I think this should do it.

But I'm not at all sure, hence am asking for guidance.

The full code listing is [here](https://gist.github.com/p-i-/1ee3548fc9573eba3b43):

Comment: What's the point of having these derived types from `Object`, when your operators always return the base `Object` type?

Comment: Maybe with a constructor `Object(Object)` which just returns its argument, and other constructors `Object(something_else)` which wrap it as needed.